# "whitespace" added automatically by browser and display "_" when i put <img> inside <a> (with the <img> on its own line)

Tags: html, image, indentation

I am using an icon in an **image** tag to use as a link to my LinkedIn and another for my Github.
Each icon is inside an **anchor** tag.

When the code is as follow:

```
<a href="temp.html" target="_blank">
   <img src="linkedinicon.png">
</a>
<a href="https://github.com/victoriensukarieh" target="_blank" title="Github">
   <img src="files/img/githubicon.png" height="30px" width="30px" style="border: none;">
</a>
```

the browser displays an "_" and in the developer tool it shows a "whitespace".

Formatting the code like this solves the problem:

```
<a href="temp.html" target="_blank"><img src="linkedinicon.png"></a>
<a href="https://github.com/victoriensukarieh" target="_blank" title="Github">
   <img src="files/img/githubicon.png" height="30px" width="30px" style="border: none;">
</a>
```

the issue can be seen here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsukarieh/uq60hyjm/1/)

does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: now its my question as well

Comment: i am planning on using font awesome for icons later, but this is intriguing me.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your link has an underline style and you do, technically, have white-space in there.

```
element.style {
}
user agent stylesheet
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This isn't really a bug, but it borders on it. Basically you would want to override the link style to use `text-decoration: none;` and it shouldn't be a problem. You might need to override all the states like a:visited and a:hover etc...

Solution: `<a style="text-decoration: none;">...</a>`

Comment: the `text-decoration` solved the issue, but I still don't understand the whitespace. putting the image tag on a new line to beautify my HTML code is displayed as whitespace?

Comment: I didn't dig too much into it, but technically there are tabs, new-lines, and possibly spaces in the code. If I was venturing a guess I also think there might be a specific behavior due to the missing image. I also didn't test it across browsers (I just used a chromium based browser). Someone with more knowledge might come along to explain the details, but my experience when developing css/html you want to use a specific style on it when you see odd behaviors so it knows what you want rather than the default. I wouldn't worry about it too much just make a class `a.img-link{...}`

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it a default anchor underline style?

Just apply style:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Make sure that this style have bigger priority than default style!

More info: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/

Comment: this worked, but why is my line breaking in the editor to format my HTML code appear as whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of the rules for white space processing (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#white-space-processing).

Images get a little weird with these rules because in some ways they get treaded as `inline` and in other ways as `inline-block`.  Line breaks, tabs, etc are whitespace characters that usually get ignored or condensed so that the elements of a webpage aren't impacted by the formatting you use to make the code readable (like indenting and new lines, as you're doing in your example).  what's happening here, though, is that ***the whitespace rules for inline elements essentially collapse any whitespace areas (groups of whitespace characters) down to a single space instead of removing it entirely***.

One of the reasons this is showing up here is that the  element is an inline element, but is being used in a way that's semantically more of a block or flex element.  If you apply `display:block` to the `a` element, the behavior will probably be closer to what you're looking for - but it will also mean you will need some additional layout styles (float, flex, etc.) to make them appear side-by-side again.  Personally, if this is intended to be a group of icon buttons/links, i would wrap them in an element (div, list, nav, etc) that's semantically correct, and apply `display:flex` to that new parent.